# Solve $\sqrt[3]{-2187}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $\sqrt[3]{-2187}$

$2187 = 3^7 \Rightarrow -2187 = (-3)^7 $

Hence $\sqrt[3]{-2187}=\sqrt[3]{(-3)^3 \cdot(-3)^3\cdot(-3)}=9\sqrt[3]{-3}$

But the answer is given as $-9\sqrt[3]{3}$. Why?

I'm assuming it is because $9\sqrt[3]{-3}=9\sqrt[3]{(-1)\cdot(3)}$ and $\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$, Hence $\Rightarrow 9\cdot(-1)\sqrt[3]{3} $

So in the end $9\sqrt[3]{-3}=-9\sqrt[3]{3}$. Is my way of thinking correct and is it convention to try to have whatever is inside the radical positive if possible? Thanks.

Comment: I think most people would argue that $-9\sqrt[3]3$ is aestetically more pleasing than $9\sqrt[3]{-3}$, but whether or not that's a specific of your exercise is your teacher's decision.

Comment: I wonder if somebody downvoted this question because you had a go. Anyway, in what domain would you like to find solutions? A sixth root of unity is a cube root of $-1$ but you won't find any of those in the real numbers.

Comment: Your way of thinking and answer is right, but doesn't $\sqrt[3]{-3}$ look more clunky than $-\sqrt[3]{3}$, even though they're the same? If I were writing an academic paper or a textbook, I would request use the latter version of the number. I don't think there's any "convention", but when something looks prettier (to me at least!) I stick to it. It's a different matter when I'm trying to teach people the difference between the expressions, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the function $x\mapsto x^3$ is an odd bijection on the real domain, so its reciprocal $\sqrt[3]{\vphantom{I}}$ has the same property (i.e. the cubic root is also bijective and odd).

i.e. Let $y=f(x)$ and $f$ odd and bijective then $$f^{-1}(-y)=f^{-1}(-f(x))=f^{-1}(f(-x))=-x=-f^{-1}(y)$$

Therefore we simply have $\sqrt[3]{-3}=-\sqrt[3]{3}$

*So your result and the one proposed in the book are fine, but the commonly adopted presentation is to get the maximum stuff out of the radical. Same reason we write $2\sqrt{2}$ rather than $\sqrt{8}$, here we can get $3^6$ out as well as the sign, so that the remaining $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is as simple as it can get. You are correct in stating that it is only a matter of convention.*

Answer (score 0):

solved(sorry for bad english):

∛2187 is the same as 2187⅓
so to get our answer  we need to muntiply a number 3 time to get that number, and if you wanna get a cubic root of a number you can just do it vice ver sa.
the steps are:

2187 = 3x3x3x3x3x3x3

⇒ 2187 = 3³x3³x3¹

Therefore, ∛2187 = ∛(3³x3³x3¹)

∛2187 = ∛(3³x3³) ∛(3¹)

= 3x3 ∛(3¹)

so ∛2187 is about 12.9802 or just ∛2187 = 9∛3.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  The question ronald christenkkson asked is why $\sqrt[3]{-2187} = -9\sqrt[3]{3}$.